# Spring Security 3 Logout not working

Tags: spring-security, logout

I am new to spring security. I have created an example in spring security 3.

I am facing a problem. I am able to login successfully with the default login page, but when I logout, I am successfully redirected to my loggedout.jsp but when check with altering URL I see that I am still logged in.

The Spring `security.xml`:

```xml
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http pattern="/loggedout.jsp" security="none" />

    <http auto-config='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/loggedout.jsp" invalidate-session="true"
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />

        <!-- <remember-me key="myAppKey" /> -->
        <!-- <session-management invalid-session-url="/timeout.jsp">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
                error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </session-management> -->
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="vrajesh" password="vrajesh"
                    authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="test" password="test"
                    authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <!--
        <http pattern="/loggedout.jsp" security="none"/>
        <http use-expressions="true">
            <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
            <form-login />
            <logout logout-success-url="/loggedout.jsp"
                delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
            <remember-me />
            <session-management invalid-session-url="/timeout.jsp">
                <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
                    error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
            </session-management>
        </http>
    -->

</beans:beans>
```

This is my logout link on every page:

```
<p><a href="j_spring_security_logout">Logout</a></p>
```

and this is my `loggedout.jsp`:

```
<p>
You have been logged out. <a href="<c:url value='/'/>">Start again</a>.
</p>
```

In my `loggedout.jsp`, if I click on the 'Start again' link it should display login page, but it does not.  Instead I am logged in the application.

Please help me and let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Please fix the HTML that you are posting, and clarify the actual configuration file you are running with. Also please clarify what link "start again" leads to. Have you enabled DEBUG logging?

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are still logged in to the application and not just seeing a browser-cached version of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problem when referencing `j_spring_security_logout`, so I did this:

1.- In `spring-security.xml` added to  section:

```
<logout logout-url="/logout.html"/>
```

2.- In my **controller** I just have:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "logout.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "loginform";
    }
```

3.- In my **.jsp**:

```
 <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout.html"><fmt:message key="text.exit" /></a>
```

And it works flawlessly :)

You can check additional logout configurations [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-logout).

Answer (score 4):

Your logout link on every page should be:

```
<p><a href="/j_spring_security_logout">Logout</a></p>
```